# /etc/shadow encryption method

Tags: shadow

http://www.aychedee.com/2012/03/14/etc_shadow-password-hash-formats/

From the above article I can see the password can be encrypt in abot 6 different ways to genereate the hash in the format of $1$ ...

However, when I read the shadow file of my machine, I get something like this

```
root:l2tdfsoZQxobQ:15743:0:99999:7:::
bin:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
daemon:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
adm:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
lp:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
sync:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
shutdown:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
halt:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
mail:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
news:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
uucp:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
operator:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
games:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
gopher:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
ftp:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
nobody:*:13653:0:99999:7:::
dbus:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
vcsa:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
rpm:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
haldaemon:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
pcap:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
nscd:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
named:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
netdump:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
sshd:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
rpc:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
mailnull:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
smmsp:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
rpcuser:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
nfsnobody:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
apache:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
squid:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
webalizer:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
xfs:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
ntp:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
mysql:!!:13653:0:99999:7:::
```

For the root password, it is like l2tdfsoZQxobQ, so what encryption method did the system use for this password?

Comment: It's worth noting that DES is fairly easy to crack. You should change your root password and never use it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hashing algorithm isn't listed in the password field, it's usually because it's in [traditional DES-based `crypt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)#Traditional_DES-based_scheme) form. The hash you've provided even looks like a crypt hash.

Examples of what other DES hashes look like:

```
[root@xxx601 ~]# openssl passwd -crypt myPass
7BQrU5yVqiGqU
[root@xxx601 ~]# openssl passwd -crypt newPass
Mbq6MsDxJOsow
[root@xxx601 ~]#
```

Crypt hashes are typically the weakest possible hashes for a variety of reasons. Not the least of which is that it can only support passwords up to eight characters so all characters after the eighth are just ignored.

Comment: Will it be decrypt easily?

Comment: Relative to other hashing algorithms yeah. Brute forcing isn't quick no matter the hashing algorithm though.

Comment: I theory hashes can not be decrypted, (not by anyone, not by the computer, no way, no how). However sometimes hash algorithms are weak. There is also the brute force method.

Comment: Can that be DES? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:frgdoDCfRcIJ:pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/john-the-ripper-hash-formats+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=hk

Comment: I'm not going to help you crack someone else's password if you don't know it already. But to answer your question, `crypt` is a DES implementation. It's the 5th or so example on that second page.

Comment: @TimothyLeung Yes, this is the historical DES-based hash, and it can be decrypted now. The algorithm itself is still considered strong in that it can only be cracked by brute force, but brute force is only 56 bits which is doable with today's computing power. So do consider your password compromised now that you've posted this hash on the Internet.

Comment: @Gilles Regarding your edit, I don't know if we should treat the two as synonyms. "crypt" involves things such as truncating the password which isn't necessarily DES. Looking online there's an "extended DES" implementation that supports longer passwords and uses DES but is still a different hashing algorithm than older crypt hashes.

Comment: @Bratchley That's not DES, it's DES-based crypt (as opposed to MD5-based crypt, SHA2-based crypt, etc. — the recent algorithms are still part of crypt).

Comment: I'm more referring to the edits that refer to "DES hashes" which implies that all hashing algorithms that employ DES will look like this and that they all have the eight character limit.