# Where are user account passwords kept on Debian?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, password, password-store

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I'm wondering where I can find the hashes for the user account passwords.

Comment: In `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of [/etc/shadow encryption method](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176822/etc-shadow-encryption-method)? How was the OP supposed to find that? You need to know the answer to this question...

Comment: I agree with @stephen, there no way this question is the duplicate of _/etc/shadow encryption method_. But I'm sure that a little search on Google like "where are the passwords stored in Linux" would give the answer.

Comment: Indeed, the answer on the other question talks about how to compute the hash. A proper answer to this question would discuss `pam-auth-update` and `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`, at least. Remember also that our goal should be to not only answer the OP's question but leave a useful artifact for future visitors, so an ideal answer wouldn't just presume a default install. I.e., a future person who inherits a Debian box could find `/etc/shadow` empty-ish, and wonder "where ARE the passwords kept‽"

Comment: keeping in mind that the password may be stored in an LDAP of some sort (openldap, AD, NIS)

Answer (score 4):

User information is stored in `/etc/passwd` and passwords are stored `/etc/shadow`

Each entry in `/etc/shadow` contains the user's login, their encrypted password, and a number of fields relating to password expiration

Answer (score 1):

Total user information means

```
    1. Account Information
    2. Authentication Information
```

Account Information store in **/etc/passwd** file

Authentication Information store in **/etc/shadow** file but only **Only root user can see the information**

So if you want to see the authentication information means password information you may check the /etc/shadow file with

```
    $sudo cat /etc/shadow
```